# Getting Error in Carpal API - token_not_provided

Tags: curl

Using sandbox account, I'm getting Response:

```
string(30) "{"error":"token_not_provided"}"
```

Don't get this error in documentation of carpal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Carpal API- 
Every endpoint requires you to authenticate with a JSON token and you will have to pass a header to every request. And this authentication be a token

[See 1.2 Authentication](https://www.carpal.me/developers/api-v2/)

First generate token and add it to header of your curl request.

Comment: Thanks for your help